# Static variables data is not reflecting for the first time when the application runs and reflecting from the second time onwards in android

Tags: android

i am using static string variables in my project for multi 
language application in android..
these string values are initialized with their default values
 i.e English language values..
When the user clicks on change language option i am getting the
 language code of that respective language and appending the language
 code to url,connecting to server and fetching data which is xml format
 and  assigning the fetched values to their respective Strings.
For the first time when the user selects the language ...the values were
 not changed and default english lang values are shown on the screens..
For the second time when the user Selects Language at this time All values are changing..
This issue is occurring when the application is running for the first time..
My code is:

```
public class MenuScreen extends Activity {


    // TextView Elements
    TextView backup_text=null;  
    TextView restore_text=null;
    TextView terms_text =null;
    TextView  settings_text=null;
    TextView  about_text=null;
    TextView  contactus_text=null;
    TextView  exit_text=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);


    // Setting here the changed values  

        backup_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_backup);

        backup_text.setText(Strings.BACKUP);

//Strings.BACKUP contains the changed values of language

         restore_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_restore);
         restore_text.setText(Strings.RESTORE);

          terms_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_terms);
         terms_text.setText(Strings.TERMS);

         settings_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_settings);
         settings_text.setText(Strings.SETTINGS);

         about_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_aboutus);
         about_text.setText(Strings.ABOUT);

          contactus_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_contactus);
         contactus_text.setText(Strings.CONTACT_US);

          exit_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_logout);
         exit_text.setText(Strings.EXIT);
```

Comment: better to use shared preference

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem & code correctly, the language is not changed for the first time because it **has been loaded** with **old** language.

The simplest way that i can think is to move all of your setText code :

```
about_text.setText(Strings.ABOUT);
//and all setText code
```

To the `onClick` or anything you like, so when the user click a button (for example), the text will be changed with the new **language**.

Feel free to comment if i miss understood you.

Comment: the set.text values are not reflecting for the first time only..from the second time onward i am getting the changed values only..when i am using the debugging mode the values are changing for the first time also..this is my issue

Comment: "the values are changing for the first time" yes, the values are changing but it will not be displayed if you dont call setText again...

Comment: I think refreshing the screen may work...because when i am clicking  the change language again...and this time i am not at all selecting any language and clicking on cancel button...the previous changed values are reflecting on the screen..why to use set text again when i am already setting the value...please explain me in detail...

Comment: Give you mail id.. i will mail you